# Package dataset not being recognized as an object

Tags: r

Yesterday I was using the `BostonHousing` dataset from the `mlbench` package in a shiny app and everything was working smoothly. Now, when I try and reload the dataset, it's not appearing anywhere in RStudio, despite it appearing when calling `data(package = "mlbench")`. Below is the code I'm using:

```
library(mlbench)
data(package = "mlbench") ## boston housing appears here
BostonHousing
```

Running BostonHousing returns the following error:

```
Error: object 'BostonHousing' not found
```

I'm not sure what's going on. mlbench is loaded. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, but nothing works. Whereas previously I would see BostonHousing with the pink box next to it, now I see nothing.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Run `data(BostonHousing)`

Comment: Use this instead:library(MASS);
boston <- Boston